# how can I eliminate redundant fields containing data from json with jq

Tags: json, jq, edit

I have json that has info enclosed in type and data structures that need to be removed. I have a stucture like:

```
{
  "Board: WEC": {
    "ExprMap": {
      "data": {
        "noAddr": {
          "ExprString": {
            "data": "11112aoa6NLYomYZro566XZVGEXyCDqeqDcp8Pzg81Ckuws6SexC99"
          }
        },
        "shortDesc": {
          "ExprString": {
            "data": "Wile E. Coyote for Board Member"
          }
        },
        "yesAddr": {
          "ExprString": {
            "data": "11112gUFvJR6JBDYJURETaWUBpEDa1EyjgRHFncEfQ4hGECnciPnhw"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Board: DaD": {
    "ExprMap": {
      "data": {
        "noAddr": {
          "ExprString": {
            "data": "11112Cwtg2Bs4WUAYrXhL9xZXXSXr9Gn62Cty39RhUaBnqjrKkqwAZ"
          }
        },
        "shortDesc": {
          "ExprString": {
            "data": "Daffy Duck for Board Member"
          }
        },
        "yesAddr": {
          "ExprString": {
            "data": "1111TnFUN7eZBWXp3QQACQRRxpcS5uH5Bpf67vikWhA5e3F6ikAmU"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to eliminate the extraneous nesting of

- "ExprMap": { "data": KEEP-THIS } }
- "ExprString": { "data": KEEP-THIS } }
  to get

```
    {
      "Board: WEC": {
        "noAddr": "11112aoa6NLYomYZro566XZVGEXyCDqeqDcp8Pzg81Ckuws6SexC99",
        "shortDesc": "Wile E. Coyote for Board Member",
        "yesAddr": "11112gUFvJR6JBDYJURETaWUBpEDa1EyjgRHFncEfQ4hGECnciPnhw"
      },
      "Board: DaD": {
        "noAddr": "11112Cwtg2Bs4WUAYrXhL9xZXXSXr9Gn62Cty39RhUaBnqjrKkqwAZ",
        "shortDesc": "Daffy Duck for Board Member",
        "yesAddr": "1111TnFUN7eZBWXp3QQACQRRxpcS5uH5Bpf67vikWhA5e3F6ikAmU"
      }
```

help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I believe to be a solution to the extended problem presented in the comments.  That is, it handles ExprTuple, ExprList, ExprMap, and ExprString, and can easily be extended to cover other "Expr" types.

```
def detype:
  if type == "object"
  then if has("ExprTuple") then .ExprTuple.data | map(detype)
       elif has("ExprList") then .ExprList.data | map(detype)
       elif has("ExprMap") then .ExprMap.data | detype
       elif has("ExprString") then .ExprString.data
       else . end
  else . end;

walk(detype)
```

Answer (score 0):

`map_values` is up to the task, or at least the following jq expression does the job:

```
map_values( .ExprMap.data | map_values(.ExprString.data) )
```

Comment: That worked for the example I gave. I tried extending it to wor for other examples.

Comment: but got the error " Cannot iterate over null (null)"
the data was:
```
"expr": {
      "ExprTuple": {
        "data": [
          {
            "ExprString": {
              "data": "Value from registry"
            }
          },
          {
            "ExprList": {
              "data": [
                {
                  "ExprString": {
                    "data": "111125wZXiQzy3EHP8af72ukF4aamjUjBxx7vgTd54CWj2UewWPgQC"
            ...
   ` ` `
how can we get rid of all the ExprTuple.data and ExprList.data as well?

Comment: Please see the solution with `def detype`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a more generic approach:

```
walk(if type == "object"
     then if has("ExprMap") then del(.ExprMap) + (.ExprMap.data | map_values(.ExprString.data)) else . end
     else . end)
```

Comment: I tried:  walk(if type == "object"
     then if has("ExprMap") then del(.ExprMap) + (.ExprMap.data | map_values(.ExprString.data)) else (
             if has("ExprTuple") then del(.ExprTuple) + (.ExprTuple.data | map_values(.ExprString.data)) else (
                     if has("ExprList") then del(.ExprList) + (.ExprList.data | map_values(.ExprString.data)) else . end)` but I got invalid charater and Possibly unterminated 'if' statement  Adding parentesis did not help...